# Can I track multiple checkboxes with React Hooks or do I need to use a Class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I'm learning React Hooks and trying to understand how I can manage multiple checkboxes with state. If I only have one checkbox, my code below works - using `check` as state - but when I have multiple boxes, this doesn't work because `onChange = {() => setCheck(!check)}` will change the check state for ALL of the boxes at once.

I think it's doable if I use a React class component (something like `this.handleCheckboxChange` to only change state for the particular checkbox) but I'm trying to see if it's possible to do this with hooks.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Search = ({ options }) => {
    const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);

    const renderedOptions = options.map((option) => {
        return (
            <div key={option}>
                <label>
                    <input
                        checked={check ? 'checked' : ''}
                        type="checkbox"
                        name={option}
                        value={option}
                        onChange={() => {
                            setCheck(!check);
                        }}></input>
                    {option}
                </label>
            </div>
        );
    });

    return (
        <form>
            <label>Search Engines (check all that apply)</label>
            {renderedOptions}
        </form>
    );
};

export default Search;
```

Comment: This has zero to do with hooks vs. classes. All you need (whether in a function or a class based component) is a state array. `const [check, setCheck] = useState(options.map(_ => false))` and basic state array code to update it. You can also use an object and use `option` as the key.

Comment: Just saw your edits, thanks. I'll work on that.

Comment: @ChrisG Actually, I do have a question. I have figured out how to do it with an object, but not with an array - how do I target the event for one particular checkbox if I don't have a key?
Let's say I create a handleChange function (`const handleChange = (e) => { **setCheck** }`), and in the checkbox rendering put `onChange={handleChange]`. What would `setCheck` look like since `e.target.value` isn't in my state array of booleans?

Comment: You'd use `options.map((option, i)` and use something like `e => setState([...check, [i]: e.target.checked])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object as the state, with each propname as the name of the checkbox and can hold the checked information as value.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({});
handleChange = (e) => setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked });
```

You can bind the options as initial or default values to the state. And <input value={values[options.name]